# How to send and trap a signal sent to a PID, using C

Tags: c, process, signals

Suppose, i know the process of my parent id and would like to

```
kill(my_parent_id, SIGTERM)
```

As a parent process, how can i catch this signal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register to catch the signal:

```
void termination_handler(int sig)
{
   /* do something */
}

struct sigaction handler;

handler.sa_handler = termination_handler;
sigemptyset (&handler.sa_mask);
handler.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;

sigaction(SIGTERM, &handler, NULL);
```

Here is a good [example page](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Sigaction-Function-Example.html).

You could use the old style, but it is not suggested:

```
void termination_handler()
{
    /* do something */
}

signal(SIGTERM, termination_handler);
```

Comment: Right. This works fine i use "signal". In event i send a kill command to a particular PID, as that process how do i determine that a signal was sent my way?

Comment: You almost surely want `handler.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;`. Non-restarting signals will badly break code that does not expect to get `EINTR` and does not handle it.

Comment: guys ... i am definitely missing something here. can you possibly provide an example where signal is sent to a pid via a kill command?

Comment: You can get your parent ID using `getppid()`, and send it signals using: `kill(getppid(), SIGTERM);` Probably want to be sure you know who you are sending the signal too.

Comment: If i am receiving a signal from somewhere outside of my program, how do i set up a listener, so i can act on it?

Comment: That's what the code above, in my example, showed. The handler _is_ the listener.